Providing an Authentic Finish to a TIKZ Gold Plate
I am under the assumption that the RGB color formula for pure gold is (255,215,0).
Consider the code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\definecolor{DarkRed}{RGB}{139,0,0}
\definecolor{PureGold}{RGB}{255,215,0}

\def\theLetterSpace{0.5pt}
\def\theWordSpace{1.5\LocalLetterSpace}
\newlength\LocalLetterSpace
\newcommand\spaceout[2][\theLetterSpace]{%
  \setlength\LocalLetterSpace{#1}\expandafter\spaceouthelpA#2 \relax\relax}
\def\spaceouthelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \spaceouthelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \kern\theWordSpace\spaceouthelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\spaceouthelpB#1#2\relax{%
  #1%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \kern\LocalLetterSpace\spaceouthelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}
 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\tikzset{mydecor/.style 2 args={decoration={text along path,
        text align={left indent=1.5em},
        text={|\bfseries\tiny|#2},
        },
      yshift=#1,
      decorate}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\draw[color=PureGold,fill=DarkRed] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);
\draw[color=PureGold,fill=PureGold] (0,0) circle (2.6cm);
\draw[color=PureGold,fill=PureGold] (0,0) circle (2.43cm);
\end{scope}

\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1.5ex,text along path, 
reverse path,text align=center, text={|\LARGE\spaceout[3.5pt]\bfseries\color{PureGold}|GOLD}}}] (-30:3.05cm) arc (-30:210:3.05cm);
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1.25ex,text along path, text align=center,
text={|\LARGE\scalefont{0.97}\spaceout[3.5pt]\bfseries\color{PureGold}|PLATE}}}] (192.5:3.07cm) arc (192.5:345:3.07cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}

which produces

QUESTION: How may the above code be modified in order to give a shining metallic finish to the words and the gold portion of the above "gold plate"?
Thank you.

Is cabin really essential to your question? Is there some reason to reinvent letter spacing?

You could draw a black disc with opacity that varies by angle. The opacity formula pictured is k·sin²(2θ), with k=.04 (so that the opacity oscillates between 0 and k). Larger values of k will make the darker regions more dark. Another good opacity function is k·(1+sin(4θ)). A more complicated example is below.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\definecolor{DarkRed}{RGB}{139,0,0}
\definecolor{PureGold}{RGB}{255,215,0}

\def\theLetterSpace{0.5pt}
\def\theWordSpace{1.5\LocalLetterSpace}
\newlength\LocalLetterSpace
\newcommand\spaceout[2][\theLetterSpace]{%
  \setlength\LocalLetterSpace{#1}\expandafter\spaceouthelpA#2 \relax\relax}
\def\spaceouthelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \spaceouthelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \kern\theWordSpace\spaceouthelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\spaceouthelpB#1#2\relax{%
  #1%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \kern\LocalLetterSpace\spaceouthelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}
 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\tikzset{mydecor/.style 2 args={decoration={text along path,
        text align={left indent=1.5em},
        text={|\bfseries\tiny|#2},
        },
      yshift=#1,
      decorate}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=PureGold,fill=DarkRed] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);
\draw[color=PureGold,fill=PureGold] (0,0) circle (2.6cm);

\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1.5ex,text along path, 
reverse path,text align=center, text={|\LARGE\spaceout[3.5pt]\bfseries\color{PureGold}|GOLD}}}] (-30:3.05cm) arc (-30:210:3.05cm);
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1.25ex,text along path, text align=center,
text={|\LARGE\scalefont{0.97}\spaceout[3.5pt]\bfseries\color{PureGold}|PLATE}}}] (192.5:3.07cm) arc (192.5:345:3.07cm);
\foreach \t in {1,...,360}
    \fill[black, fill opacity={.04*(sin(2*\t))^2}] (0,0)--(\t:3.5) arc (\t:\t+2:3.5) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}

As an aside, you might consider a simpler way to draw the image:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
 
\definecolor{DarkRed}{RGB}{139,0,0}
\definecolor{PureGold}{RGB}{255,215,0}
 
\tikzset{
    mydecor/.style={line width=9mm, DarkRed, 
        decoration={text along path, text align=center, raise=-6pt,
        text={|\color{PureGold}\bfseries\sffamily\LARGE\,|#1}},
        postaction=decorate}
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[mydecor=GOLD] (180:3.05)arc(180:0:3.05);
\draw[mydecor=PLATE] (180:3.05)arc(180:360:3.05);
\fill[PureGold] (0,0) circle (2.6cm);

\foreach \t in {1,...,360}
    \fill[black, fill opacity={.04*(sin(2*\t))^2}] (0,0)--(\t:3.5) arc (\t:\t+2:3.5) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}

You can make the opacity function more complicated if you don't like the symmetry of the "shininess". Any periodic, function with period 360° and 0≤f≤1 will work. For best results, I suggest min=0 and max<<1. For example:
fill opacity={.04*(2+sin(4*\t)+.8*sin(3*(\t+40)))}



I knew that somebody would produce a shiny one before I posted anything ;). How do you come up with the function?

Many thanks for this answer.

@cfr: I did an image search for "shiny metallic disk". The effect appears to be created by alternating dark and light portions, so I needed a function that oscillated between 0 and some small positive number. I picked k*(sin(2*\t))^2. Another good possibility is k*(1+sin(4*\t)). Of course, you can change the frequency in the sine function to get more or fewer dark regions.

Thanks. I wouldn't be able to come up with that, but it makes sense. Thank you.

Here's another option using some code for false shading per iteration that I used for controll over shapes and image + tikz add path image background example and Draw 3 dimensional ring one.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\definecolor{DarkRed}{RGB}{139,0,0}
\definecolor{PureGold}{RGB}{255,215,0}

\def\ShadeButton(#1)[#2][#3][#4]#5#6{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
        \shade[left color=#5, right color=#5!50!PureGold,shading angle=135] (0,0) circle (#2);
        \shade[left color=#5, right color=#5!50!PureGold,shading angle=-45] (0,0) circle (#2-1.5mm);
        \path [path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center){
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \shade[outer color=#5, inner color=#5!70!PureGold,shading = radial] (0mm,0mm) circle (#2*5);
                    \path(0,0) -- (-6.5*#2,-6.5*#2);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            };}](0,0) circle (#2-3mm)node[align=center,xscale=#3,yscale=#4]{#6};
    \end{scope}
}
\tikzset{
    mydecor/.style={draw=none,
        decoration={text along path, text align=center, raise=-6pt,
            text={|\color{PureGold}\bf\sffamily\LARGE\,|#1}},
        postaction=decorate}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \ShadeButton(0,0)[38mm][1][1.2]{DarkRed}{}
        \draw[mydecor=GOLD] (180:3.05)arc(180:0:3.05);
        \draw[mydecor=PLATE] (180:3.05)arc(180:360:3.05);
        \ShadeButton(0,0)[26mm][2][1.2]{PureGold!50!gray}{\Huge 50\\ \rmfamily JX5893\\ \tiny not enigmatic \\[-1em] \tiny content}
        %\fill[PureGold] (0,0) circle (2.6cm);
        
        \foreach \r in {110,110+180,130,130+180,0,180,45,45+180}{%forced radial shade
            \foreach \i [evaluate={\s=10}] in {0,1,...,30}{
                \fill [black, fill opacity=1/40]
                (\r+\s-\i:2.6cm) -- (\r+\s-\i:2.6cm+1cm)
                arc (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:2.6cm+1cm) -- (\r-\s+\i:2.6cm) arc (\r-\s+\i:\r+\s-\i:2.6cm);
            }
        }
        
        \foreach \r in {45-15,45-10,45-5,45,45+5,45+10,45+15}{%forced radial shade v2
            \foreach \i [evaluate={\s=25}] in {0,1,...,15}{
                \fill [black, fill opacity=1/100]
                (\r+\s-\i:2.3cm)
                arc (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:2.3cm) -- (\r+\s-\i+180:2.3cm) arc (\r+\s-\i+180:\r-\s+\i+180:2.3cm) -- cycle;
            }
        }
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Many thanks for posting this very nice alternative answer.
