How to Reproduce This Tikz Colorization?
A little while back, I inquired about placing an authentic metallic finish on a gold plate: Providing an Authentic Finish to a TIKZ Gold Plate
One of Sandy G's very nice answers:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\definecolor{DarkRed}{RGB}{139,0,0}
\definecolor{PureGold}{RGB}{255,215,0}

\def\theLetterSpace{0.5pt}
\def\theWordSpace{1.5\LocalLetterSpace}
\newlength\LocalLetterSpace
\newcommand\spaceout[2][\theLetterSpace]{%
  \setlength\LocalLetterSpace{#1}\expandafter\spaceouthelpA#2 \relax\relax}
\def\spaceouthelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \spaceouthelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \kern\theWordSpace\spaceouthelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\spaceouthelpB#1#2\relax{%
  #1%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \kern\LocalLetterSpace\spaceouthelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}
 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\tikzset{mydecor/.style 2 args={decoration={text along path,
        text align={left indent=1.5em},
        text={|\bfseries\tiny|#2},
        },
      yshift=#1,
      decorate}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=PureGold,fill=DarkRed] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);
\draw[color=PureGold,fill=PureGold] (0,0) circle (2.6cm);

\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1.5ex,text along path, 
reverse path,text align=center, text={|\LARGE\spaceout[3.5pt]\bfseries\color{PureGold}|GOLD}}}] (-30:3.05cm) arc (-30:210:3.05cm);
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1.25ex,text along path, text align=center,
text={|\LARGE\scalefont{0.97}\spaceout[3.5pt]\bfseries\color{PureGold}|PLATE}}}] (192.5:3.07cm) arc (192.5:345:3.07cm);
\foreach \t in {1,...,360}
    \fill[black, fill opacity={.04*(sin(2*\t))^2}] (0,0)--(\t:3.5) arc (\t:\t+2:3.5) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}

which in Sandy G's post, produces:

However, when I run the same code, my output looks like this:

QUESTION: Can anyone explain the reason for the visual difference in the two outputs generated by the same code? I have compiled the code twice with two different versions of TeXstudio; the most recent being 4.7.3, and I seem in both cases to get the same visual output which does not match the colorization displayed in the said answer. Does anyone have any suggestions how I may match Sandy G's output in terms of colorization?
Thank you.

not entirely clear what differences you see but did you try the edit for thr final version, specifcally using fill opacity={.04*(2+sin(4*\t)+.8*sin(3*(\t+40)))}

@DavidCarlisle I ran both versions---both results are the same; that in, both produced gold shadings (at least to my eyes) different from the posted answer.

@DavidCarlisle When you run the code, does your output well match that of Sandy G?

no closer to yours but it's all highly dependent on the pdf viewer used and your physical screen how much the shading blurs. but like you I get the darker "cross" in the middle whereas the one shown the centre is lighter

Maybe it is a problem with operating systems and color management, using a color picker in Windows I have these values ​​for the colors you want: \definecolor{DarkRed}{RGB}{117, 20, 12} and \definecolor{PureGold}{RGB}{249, 215, 73} and the result seems to resemble the one that Sandy G's produces

@JLeonV. Many thanks for both of these color suggestions.

Thank you @DavidCarlisle.

Bear in mind that you're seeing a converted version here and not the original PDF. So unless you know you're converting in the same way, the same PDF may give different results when posted here. I originally posted an answer there which produced a darker gold. If you overlay the shine, I prefer it as it is less yellowy, but I'm not sure it is worth the additional computation.

@JLeonV. The color suggestions you made in your earlier comment work very nicely. Perhaps you will consider posting this as an answer---as the question asks for what can be done to reproduce the desired output.  Thank you, once again.

I originally posted this as an answer to your earlier question, but I deleted it because it didn't really shine. Basically, my answer was focused on improving the colour because real gold is not generally as yellow. Of course, the colour of gold varies depending on a large number of factors, including age, but, intuitively, I thought a darker colour looked more authentic.

In my deleted answer, I then experimented by overlaying the functional shading from Sandy G.'s answer, because I wanted to see if I could create a subtler and slightly less yellowy effect:

\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/719760/ addaswyd o gwestiwn DDS: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/719752/
\usetikzlibrary{shadings,decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\definecolor{DarkRed}{RGB}{139,0,0}
\definecolor{PureGold}{RGB}{255,215,0}

\def\theLetterSpace{0.5pt}
\def\theWordSpace{1.5\LocalLetterSpace}
\newlength\LocalLetterSpace
\newcommand\spaceout[2][\theLetterSpace]{%
  \setlength\LocalLetterSpace{#1}\expandafter\spaceouthelpA#2 \relax\relax}
\def\spaceouthelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \spaceouthelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \kern\theWordSpace\spaceouthelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\spaceouthelpB#1#2\relax{%
  #1%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \kern\LocalLetterSpace\spaceouthelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}
 

\tikzset{%
  mydecor/.style 2 args={%
    decoration={text along path,
      text align={left indent=1.5em},
      text={|\bfseries\tiny|#2},
    },
    yshift=#1,
    decorate,
  },
}

\tikzset{/gold/.cd,
  dim/.store in=\golddim,
  no/.store in=\goldno,
  dim=10mm,
  no=6,
}
\colorlet{goldbase}{yellow!50!orange}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
    \draw[color=PureGold,fill=DarkRed] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);
    \draw[color=PureGold,fill=PureGold] (0,0) circle (2.6cm);
    \draw[color=PureGold,fill=PureGold] (0,0) circle (2.43cm);
  \end{scope}
  
  \path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1.5ex,text along path, 
      reverse path,text align=center, text={|\LARGE\spaceout[3.5pt]\bfseries\color{PureGold}|GOLD}}}] (-30:3.05cm) arc (-30:210:3.05cm);
  \path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1.25ex,text along path, text align=center,
      text={|\LARGE\scalefont{0.97}\spaceout[3.5pt]\bfseries\color{PureGold}|PLATE}}}] (192.5:3.07cm) arc (192.5:345:3.07cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{/gold/.cd,dim=26mm,}
  \colorlet{goldbase}{PureGold}
  \draw[color=PureGold,line width=.5mm] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \d using {(\i/\goldno)},evaluate=\i as \j using {(\i*90)/\goldno},evaluate=\j as \k using {\j/45},evaluate=\j as \m using {\j/30}] in {0,1,...,\goldno} \fill [preaction={fill=goldbase},top color=gray!\j!,bottom color=gray!\k,middle color=gray!\m,shading=axis,opacity=0.25]  (0,0) coordinate (-a) circle ({35mm+(\d mm)});
  \draw[fill=DarkRed] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);
  \fill [preaction={fill=goldbase}, left color=gray!50!black, right color=gray!50!black, middle color=gray!50, shading=axis, opacity=0.25]
  (0,0) coordinate (-a) circle (\golddim);
  \fill[preaction={fill=goldbase}, top color=gray!90!, bottom color=gray!2, middle color=gray!30, shading=axis, opacity=0.25] (-a)  circle (\golddim);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

